# Pass JVM Opts from build.sbt to startup script in Play Framework 2.2.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, sbt-native-packager

Is there possibility to configure/pass JVM options (ie. javaagent) from build.sbt to stage build - to be used by a generated startup script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the start script generated by sbt-native-packager, when using the JavaAppPackaging or JavaServerPackaging archetype, you can modify it using the SBT setting `bashScriptExtraDefines`

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/cheatsheet.html?highlight=bashscriptextradefines#overriding-templates

You can use a number of functions and variables which are already defined in the bash start script. `addJava` adds flags to the java binary. `addApp` adds flags to the args passed to the running Java application. `app_home` points at the directory containing the start script.

An example (assuming you have made the `newrelic.jar` file available to the staged environment via the `mappings` setting):

```
bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava "-javaagent:${app_home}/../newrelic/newrelic.jar""""
```

Or

```
bashScriptExtraDefines += "addApp -Dhttps.port=9001"
```

Comment: In case it helps anyone, this `bashScriptExtraDefines` technique also works when packaging as a Docker image.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your .sbt file

`javaOptions += "-Xmx2G"`

Full documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Examples/Quick-Configuration-Examples.html